# Unable to exclude Program files (86) folder with Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, path

I seem to be able to exclude any map with powershell using the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Exclude windows,program files  -Recurse  | 
    where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'}  |
    ForEach-Object {$_.FullName} > $search_pro
```

not `Program Files (86)` though? any thoughts on why this is.

thank you in advance

I typed the full name of the map but it refused.

Comment: In short: arguments that contains _spaces_ (and/or other metacharacters, such as `(`, `)` and `&`) must be _quoted_, e.g, `'Program Files'`). See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: As an aside: Due to the lack of quoting, `-Exclude windows,program files` also doesn't work as you intend: `files` becomes its own argument, which positionally binds to the `-Filter` parameter.

Comment: thank you very much for sharing your knowledge, I feel like I was able to resolve the issue.